# CS50 algorithms - how to solve loop for print_winner() function

Tags: c, cs50

In order to solve the print_winner() function I'm trying to first sort the candidate array and once that's done print out the name of the last candidate in the array.

I think I'm pretty close (or far :p) to the answer but my compiler keeps returning: (null).

Any help please? In the simplest terms possible as I'm quite new to programming, thanks!

Here's my code thus far:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
        //hier wordt vote gecalled, waarom is dit niet zichtbaar adhv een else statement? Hoe kunnen we dit zichtbaar maken?
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    
    //sort candidate array by swap,then printf last candidate name of array.
    
    int swap; 
    
    for (int i = 0, n = candidate_count; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes > candidates[i + 1].votes)
        {
            swap = candidates[i].votes;
            candidates[i].votes = candidates[i + 1].votes; 
            candidates[i + 1].votes = swap;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", candidates[candidate_count].name);
        
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are swapping only vote counts, so `candidates[candidate_count].name` remain `NULL`.

Try this instead of your `print_winner()` function:

```
// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    
    //sort candidate array by swap,then printf last candidate name of array.
    
    candidate swap; // *** change type of swap ***
    
    for (int i = 0, n = candidate_count; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes > candidates[i + 1].votes)
        {
            // *** swap the whole structure instead of only votes ***
            swap = candidates[i];
            candidates[i] = candidates[i + 1]; 
            candidates[i + 1] = swap;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", candidates[candidate_count].name);
        
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that seems to work. Very nice, I understand the logic behind your edit. Yet something is unclear to me, in my original loop the votes correspond to the name of the candidate element, when the votes change and move position of element so to speak, then why doesn't the name move with it? Since it's the same candidate element...

Comment: @Dimi3 You wrote code to move only values of `votes` member, so only values of `votes` member moved and values of `name` member didn't move.